Как переопределить путь к файлу плагина
У меня есть плагин в котором мне нужно отредактировать один файл (include.php) но, я хочу перенести его в свою дочернюю тему чтобы после обновления нечего не слитело.
Как мне в функции (functions.php) указать перенос.
Простите если не точно виражаюсь я все еще учусь!
Часть кода которую мне нужно отредактировать.
Оригинал:
<?php if( get_theme_mod('gravatar_email') != '' || get_theme_mod('custom_profile_image') !='' ) { ?>
<div class="gravatar-wrapper">
    
    <div class="gravatar-wrapper-inner">
        <a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod('profile_link'); ?>" rel="author">                    
            <?php if( get_theme_mod('custom_profile_image') != '') { ?>
                <img width="62px" height="62px" src="<?php echo get_theme_mod('custom_profile_image'); ?>">
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php echo get_avatar( get_theme_mod('gravatar_email'), 62 ); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- BEGIN AUTHOR GRAVATAR TOOLTIP -->
    <?php if( get_theme_mod('tooltip_label') != '') { ?>
        <div class="gravatar-tooltip-wrapper">
            <?php echo get_theme_mod('tooltip_label'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- END AUTHOR GRAVATAR TOOLTIP -->
    

Oтредактированный:
        <!-- BEGIN AUTHOR GRAVATAR -->
<?php if( get_theme_mod('gravatar_email') != '' || get_theme_mod('custom_profile_image') !='' ) { ?>
<div class="gravatar-wrapper">
    
    <div class="gravatar-wrapper-inner">
        <a class="top-bar-avatar" href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>">
<?php bp_loggedin_user_avatar( 'type=thumb&width=62&height=62' ) ?>
</a>
    </div>

    <!-- BEGIN AUTHOR GRAVATAR TOOLTIP -->
    <?php if( get_theme_mod('tooltip_label') != '') { ?>
        <div class="gravatar-tooltip-wrapper">
            <?php echo get_theme_mod('tooltip_label'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- END AUTHOR GRAVATAR TOOLTIP -->

</div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- END AUTHOR GRAVATAR -->


Если я правильно понял настоящую задачу, то она состоит в переписывании функции.
Если в плагине есть проверка существования этой функции, то нет проблем - функция копируется в functions.php (или иной подключаемый файл дочки) и переписывается.
Если же проверки нет, то всё может быть намного сложнее. Конкретнее сложно сказать, не вид плагина и не зная истиной задачи.

Здравствуйте. Спасибо за помощь, я добавила часть кода для ознакомления, возможно сможете чтото подсказать!

@Lisaa код "внутренностей" функции бесполезен. Если это вообще функция. Я добавил в ответ ссылку как проверяется функция.  Вот это важно - проверка существования функции а что внутри её - вторично. Лучше ссылку на плагин давать, если он из оф каталога. Если нет - код всего файла выложенный куда-нибуть типа pastebin.com
